# How to reliably decode PDF417 barcodes on Android using software (not Zxing)?

Tags: java, android, barcode

**What I need:**

I need a java library (preferably for Android) that is capable of *reliably* decoding PDF417 barcodes, which may be distorted (not flat) and/or partially obscured.

**What I've tried:**

The Zxing PDF417 decoder is still in the alpha stages and lacks the speed and/or reliability that I require. I've tried porting the [PDF417decode project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdf417decode/) to Java; the ported library worked but was no more reliable than the Zxing implementation.

**Details:**

1. Decoding must take place in software; no external hardware is permitted
2. The library *can* cost money

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Have you had any luck with a reliable PDF417 decoder for Android?

Comment: I wasn't able to find a reliable way to accomplish this, but I stopped looking because I now work for a different company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried SDK from AIPSYS, the library is native code with android, it is very fast compared to Java code, contact the technical support for details support@aipsys.com

Comment: Since I'm now working for a different company I can't verify that this library in fact accomplishes what I was looking for, but it is the best answer. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

[Manatee Works](https://www.manateeworks.com) now offers a mobile SDK for Android and iOS that can read [PDF417](https://manateeworks.com/pdf417). It is the best!

Answer (score 2):

[PDF417.mobi](http://pdf417.mobi/) should work with distorted barcodes. We have tried with codes that are perforated, smudged, cut-off and even covered with sauce. There is a [video about that](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NGBsOOkbxyk).

Disclaimer: I work for PDF417.mobi SDK team. We developed this SDK out of frustration that other libraries weren't reliable enough.